# Problems with using shortcuts in Vaadin

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vaadin, event-propagation

I have some problems with shortcuts in Table. I have to customize some keys: delete - for removing the rows and enter to make table editable/uneditable, up/down arrows to switch mode of table from editable to uneditable. I put my Table inside transparent Panel and use Action.Handler to catch keyboard events. But when I'm writing inside TextField, TextArea, Combobox I wanted to propagate events to this component (handling delete key disable using it for deleting text in TextField and up/down keys doesn't allow open Combobox with keyboard). I saw target parameter in handleAction() method, but I don't now how to use it. Also interesting to know how to add shortcuts instead of replacing.

```
    // adding table inside Panel
    tablePanel = new Panel();
    tablePanel.setStyleName(Panel.STYLE_LIGHT);

    VerticalLayout tableElementsLayout = new VerticalLayout();
    tablePanel.setContent(tableElementsLayout);

    tablePanel.setSizeFull();
    tableElementsLayout.setSizeFull();
    vl.addComponent(tablePanel);
    vl.setExpandRatio(tablePanel, 1.0f);

    tableElementsLayout.add(table);

    // --- adding keyboard handler
    final Action actionDel = new ShortcutAction("Delete",
            ShortcutAction.KeyCode.DELETE, null);

    deleteHandler = new Action.Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleAction(Action action, Object sender, Object target) {
            // I want handle events here when I'm not inside TextField
        }

        @Override
        public Action[] getActions(Object target, Object sender) {
            return new Action[] { actionDel };
        }
    };

    tablePanel.addActionHandler(deleteHandler);
```

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: I'd like to help but I didn't completely understand your problem. Have you read Book of Vaadin: https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.shortcuts.html ? That's an excellent guide for Vaadin development.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.
I read this part of book completely and made my code according to it. I'll try to explain problem in general.
Imagine you have Panel and TextField inside it. You use Action.Handler to handle DELETE key in Panel. This block receiving symbols by TextField (So you can't delete symbols from it by keyboard). As I understand Action.Handler completely replace key handling. But I want add shortcuts listening not replace so that both TextField and Action.Handler receive keypressing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best or the most beautiful way to achieve this, but at least it works:

```
textField.addListener(new BlurListener() {
    @Override
    public void blur(BlurEvent event) {
        tablePanel.addActionHandler(deleteHandler);
    }
});

textField.addListener(new FocusListener() {
    @Override
    public void focus(FocusEvent event) {
        tablePanel.removeActionHandler(deleteHandler);
    }
});
```

These listeners will take care of the `deleteHandler` by disabling it every time the user enters the field and enabling it whenever the user leaves the field.

Comment: It looks it solves the problem, thanks. I modified this approach a little bit, I remove listeners when table is in editable mode.